# No random output with loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get random output on every loop iteration with:

```
#!/bin/bash
random() {
        shuf -i 0-9 -r -n 1
}

rnd=$(random)

until [ $rnd -ge "5" ]
do
        sleep 1
        echo $rnd
done
# I need these functions, so can't do it any simpler.
```

But what I get is:

```
./test.sh
2
2
2
2
2
2
^C
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to generate a new random number and assign it to `rnd` in each iteration of your loop. In your code you assign it once before the loop, hence it does not change and you get the same output each time.

Try moving the assignment into the loop. Something like:

```
rnd=0
until [ $rnd -ge "5" ]
do
    rnd=$(random)
    sleep 1
    echo $rnd
done
```

Comment: No problem. Feel free to select my answer as correct :)